# The header color wont change

Tags: css

i cant change the color here: http://prntscr.com/ergp4j

Can someone help me what to do? the url is: http://109.74.0.128/~assistans/

I did

```
´header.main-header .second-row .second-row-columns {
  background-color: #1c6a8b;
}`
```

but it just change a small part of it

Answer (score 0):

It's only changing "a part" of the `header` because you are targeting a child of the `header` which does not span the whole width of the page.

Change your CSS to this:

```
header.main-header .second-row {
  background-color: #1c6a8b;
}
```

See below screenshot:

[image]